# How do I deserialise an xml string in SQL Server into multiple columns?

Tags: sql-server, xml-deserialization

I am trying to deserialize xml in a SQL Server stored procedure before bringing it into c# win forms. My current result table looks as follows:

[image]

Edit: As the table above is too small to read below is an example of
what it contains:

Column 1 is just a time 07:00, 07:09, etc.
Column 2 contains the following data:
Row 1:

```
ABADILLA ARIEL<RegistrationId>29</RegistrationId>, BLAKE LORCAN<RegistrationId>30</RegistrationId>, CRONIN SHANE<RegistrationId>31</RegistrationId>
```

Row 2:

```
ADAMS NORMAN<RegistrationId>33</RegistrationId>, ADAMS WILLIAM<RegistrationId>34</RegistrationId>, AHEARNE PAUL<RegistrationId>35</RegistrationId>, LAWLOR DES<RegistrationId>32</RegistrationId>
```

So each row can have up to but no more than 4 entries.

End edit

I would like to be able to do a few things to this with this table, primarily I need to be able to modify it into the following format:

[image]

But ultimately i'd like to display the information with the name only but maintaining the link to the registration number without actually displaying it.  This part might be easier to do in c# win forms though so I think i'd be happy enough if I could get it into the format shown above.

My sql code to date to return the results table shown initialls is as follows:

```
DECLARE @Registered TABLE
(CompetitionName VARCHAR(50),
CompetitionDate  Date,
StartTime TIME,
RegistrationId INTEGER,
PlayersName  Varchar(60)
)


INSERT INTO @Registered
SELECT MAX(c.CompetitionName) AS 'Competition Name', MAX(c.[Date]) AS 'Competition Date', 
CONVERT(VARCHAR, r.PlayersStartTime, 108) AS 'Start Time', MAX(r.RegistrationId) AS RegistrationId,
CASE WHEN m.MemberId IS NOT NULL THEN (m.Surname + ' ' + m.FirstName) ELSE (nm.Surname + ' '+ nm.Firstname) END AS PlayersName
FROM dbo.Competitions c
LEFT JOIN [dbo].[Registration] r ON c.[CompetitionId] = r.[CompetitionId]
LEFT JOIN dbo.Members m ON r.MemberId = m.MemberId
LEFT JOIN dbo.NonMembers nm ON r.NonMemberId = nm.NonMemberId
WHERE [Date] = '20130104'
AND c.CompetitionId = 10
GROUP BY r.PlayersStartTime, m.MemberId, m.FirstName, m.Surname, nm.FirstName, nm.Surname
----

SELECT DISTINCT Main.StartTime, 
 STUFF((SELECT ', ' + PlayersName, + RegistrationId
  FROM @Registered list
  WHERE list.StartTime = Main.StartTime
  FOR XML PATH ('')),1,2,''
  ) AS PlayerList
FROM @Registered Main;
```

Comment: Your screenshots are too small to be of any use - can you post the table with the sample data **as text** into your question, please?

Comment: Sorry about that **marc_s**, i've added an edit to the question with text lines describing the content of the unreadable image.